# prettyphoto black thumbs with play symbol

Tags: javascript, prettyphoto

I am using `prettyphoto lightbox` to show pictures from the database.

The thumbnails are all black with play icon on them and it's not showing the image.
By the way, when you press one of this icons it refers you to the right image.
You can see my site [here](http://davidsinay.com).

In the browser URL , I am passing (e.g) : `Test2.aspx#prettyPhoto[44]/2/`
from the fireBug i pulled out the image address:
(with http in the start)
`ImageHandler.ashx?ImID=44&isLogo=false&in=On%20Air%20Card`

Please advise...

```
     <asp:DataList ID="dlLogos" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3" CellPadding="7" 
            RepeatDirection="Horizontal" ShowFooter="False" ShowHeader="False" >

    <ItemTemplate>

     <div class=hovergallery>
        <a id="imageLink"  href='<%# "ImageHandler.ashx?ImID="+ Eval("CompanyID") + "&isLogo=true" %>'  rel='<%# "prettyPhoto[" +  Eval("CompanyID") + "]" %>'  title='<%# Eval("Description") %>'   runat="server">
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" CssClass=hovergallery ImageUrl= '<%# "PPImgHandeler.ashx?ImID="+ Eval("CompanySorting") %>'  runat="server" width="300px" height="170px"  /> </a> 

        </div>

</ItemTemplate>

</asp:DataList>

<asp:DataList ID="dlNotLogos" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>


    <div style="display:none" class=hovergallery>
        <a id="imageLink"  href='<%# "ImageHandler.ashx?ImID="+ Eval("CompanyID") + "&isLogo=false&in=" + Eval("ImageName") %>'   rel='<%# "prettyPhoto[" +  Eval("CompanyID") + "]" %>'  title='<%# Eval("Description") %>'    runat="server">
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" CssClass=hovergallery ImageUrl= '<%# "PPImgHandeler.ashx?ImID="+ Eval("CompanySorting") %>'  runat="server"   width="300px" height="170px" /> </a> 
      </div>

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 0):

change from :

```
pp_images[i].match(/\b(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)\b/gi)
```

to:

```
pp_images[i].toLowerCase()
```

in the prettyPhoto.js.

and every thing worked.
hope it helps someone.